# visual studio community 2019 wont run imported project from github

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I cant get this problem to be resolved. I finally have finished my project on my pc. Now the project needs to run on my laptop. So i put the project on github via visual studio community 2019 code and imported it on my laptop also via visual studio community 2019.

Now every time i've tried to to run the program i get this error:

MSB4019 the imported project "c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Micrsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression int the import declaration "c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Micrsoft.Cpp.Default.prop" is correct and that the file exists on disk

I've tried many things too solve this problem, I tried to reinstall visual studio. I've Completly removed everthing related to visual studio (the installer and the folder with everything in it) and reinstalling it again. Downloading missing sdk software from microsoft, nothing seems to work.

And if I somehow need to change a path, i also tried that but i could not find anywhere where to edit that

This Project NEEDS to run on my laptop

project link: https://github.com/JarodIking/Game-C-

Comment: Use a `makefile` the way God (...er... K&R) intended. Don't reference machine-specific MSBuild `.props` files.

Comment: Did you check if that file exists? On either system?  Does it exist somewhere different on the other system?  It is an error message, I see no actual evidence you engaged with its content above "does not work".  Try that.  Also, look into the project files for those filenames.

Comment: i have check and there's no 'professional' directory. the file that it is searching for is in the 'community' directory, is there any way to change this? to make sure that it is looking for to community folder and not the 'professional' folder?

Comment: After looking at the files. I expect your VS variable is misconfigured here (likely from a user props file): [https://github.com/JarodIking/Game-C-/blob/master/Game/Game.vcxproj#L28](https://github.com/JarodIking/Game-C-/blob/master/Game/Game.vcxproj#L28)

Comment: Right, i see. I've been looking around too, it's the VCtargetsPath variable that has the wrong value, however i wouldnt know where to fix that variable, ill keep looking around

Answer (score 0):

Guys i fixed my issue finally, I had to set the enviroment variable path for VCtargetsPath, and i then had to fix my debugger

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.